# How to restore postgres only when there is no data

Tags: postgresql, restore, postgresql-9.6, pg-dumpall

I want to restore postgres from the output of `pg_dumpall`. However I want the restore to fail if there is any data in postgres at the moment. Is there a way to check this? In other words I want my restore to work only in a completely empty db (meaning user-defined tables).
My postgres version is 9.6

Comment: You can check `information_schema.tables` and filter on user-defined tables.  That might be sufficiently empty for you.  Just so you know, a database is not really "empty", it is filled with system stuff.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, my empty definition is only regarding the user-defined tables

Answer (score 0):

User-defined tables can be retrieved through `pg_catalog.pg_stat_user_tables` system view.